# refresh webview react native

Tags: react-native, android-webview

How can we refresh/reload previous screen in webview,
Lets say we have 2 screens A, B:
A -> B
When we go back from screen B to screen A,it goes back but with old state/data. How can we refresh it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, just add unmountInactiveRoutes:true to your createDrawerNavigator class